# vb.net: finding a position of a string within a string?

Tags: vb.net

is instr used in vb.net for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use String.IndexOf

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)** method on a string, and you can also use the VB **[InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47d6yh63.aspx)** function if you wish, although I would suggest sticking to .NET specific functions.

I would also suggest that you take a look at the [documentation of the String methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) which will help you know what functionality is available in the framework when working with strings. You can also take a look at the [documentation for VB-specific string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: The pros and cons of the VB-specific functions like Instr are discussed in other questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft.visualbasic

Answer (score 2):

no [indexof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) is

Comment: -1 for the "no" because Instr **is** available and used in VB.Net, so the answer is wrong as it stands.

Comment: @MarkJ, problem with instr, it doesn't know when it's an empty string and when the position is found at index 0, both return 0 and you need to handle null.